# Is there a way to detect OS in fish shell akin to the OSTYPE variable in bash?

Tags: fish, os-detection

Right now I'm forced to resort to using `uname` to get the operating system name and it works. But in `bash` there is the `OSTYPE` environment variable that is automatically set and I was wondering if there is something similar.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [fish user documentation](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_conditionals) it seems that the canonical way to execute code conditionally depending on the operating system type is using a `switch` statement with the `uname` results. See example:

```
switch (uname)
    case Linux
            echo Hi Tux!
    case Darwin
            echo Hi Hexley!
    case FreeBSD NetBSD DragonFly
            echo Hi Beastie!
    case '*'
            echo Hi, stranger!
end
```